# page load in IE11 empty

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem when i try to load a product' s page of Aliexpress.com on Internet explorer. This is an exemple https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000178715895.html
It works good with all other browsers but nothing on internet explorer, it is as no contents is loaded.
I am sure it is a problem on their own side because if i try to check the ie' s console i find out a lot of errors of compatibility expecially with their scripts. Because of i need to open their page with IE11 i am trying to find out a solution for that, something like IE' s settings or other that can help me to skip the problem. I have tried a lot of different configurations of IE but nothing. The problem is the same with different computers, operative systems and different internet connections and providers.
Hope someone can help!

Comment: Have you tried the compatibility mode in IE11?

Comment: yes, i have tried compatibility mode and nothing changed. The structure is visible (as non-compatibility mode), but diferently formatted but everything is empty. Have you checked if it works for you ?

Comment: No, not on IE11

Comment: I think that's because the website uses some scripts not compatible with IE, such as ES6 syntax. This can't be changed by just modifying the configurations in IE. Only developing another version that can compatible with IE can solve the issue. Why you have to open the site in IE 11?

Comment: @YuZhou it is exactly the problem. However it seems they have fixed it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to open it with IE just now and it can work well.